# Redmine configuration - Rake: Don´t know how to build task environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, redmine

I´m configuring Redmine for the first time. Everything works fine except for the incoming emails part.
I have downloaded the latest version of email.rake
and I´m invoking it using the following command:

rake -f "C:\Archivos de programa\BitNami Redmine Stack\apps\redmine\lib\tasks\email.rake" RAILS_ENV=production redmine:email:receive_pop3 host=foohost username=user password=pass

I get:

...(in C:/Archivos de programa/BitNami Redmine Stack/ruby/bin)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'environment'

I have read a similar message in the forum but I couldn´t understand how to solve it.

I´m running windows btw.

I wasn´t sure if this question should be here or in serverfault.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `C:\Archivos de programa\BitNami Redmine Stack\apps\redmine\Rakefile` as the rake file. It will make all other rake tasks (including the email ones) in Redmine automatically available.